# Handle tap on CustomPainter - Flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas, dart

I am building this simple 
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo50d.png)

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: CircuitPainter(),
        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in my CircuitPainter I'm painting few TrainSwitch which are also extending CustomPainter.

```
class CircuitPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    ...

    // First switch
    Point origin = new Point(size.width * 0.05, bottomHeight);
    Point endCurveFirstSwitch = new Point(size.width * 0.20, middleHeight);
    Point firstMiddlePoint = new Point(size.width * 0.30, middleHeight);
    Point firstBottomPoint = new Point(size.width * 0.20, bottomHeight);
    TrainSwitch firstSwitch = new TrainSwitch(
        origin, firstBottomPoint, firstMiddlePoint,
        endCurve: endCurveFirstSwitch);
    firstSwitch.paint(canvas, size);
```

I want to do actions when I'm clicking on a switch. I found some topics but they always advise to wrap the CustomPaint in GestureDetector but in my case I want to detect on each TrainSwitch, how to do that ?

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/fc8c1bcc0a4fe67f04b05f3bb0c35e37

Comment: I managed to do it with the Listener. Not sure I'm doing things right but it works thanks !